# populate many to many table from existing tables

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many

I have two existing tables with data populated

table A 
--tableA_id
--contentA

table B
--tableB_id
--contentB

Now, I want to create a many to many relationship table

table A_B
--tableA_id
--tableB_id

the question is that how to write a sql script (I am new to sql) to populate table A_B using the existing data from table A and table B. Many thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to populate table A_B, you'd have to do this:

```
INSERT INTO A_B (tableA_id, tableB_id)
SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM A CROSS JOIN B
```

CROSS JOIN will relate each row in table A with each row in table B.

If you want to relate some rows in table A with some rows in table B, you need to be more specific, and do something like:

```
INSERT INTO A_B (tableA_id, tableB_id)
SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.some_field = B.some_other_field
```

Comment: Ace - just saved me 800 insert statements or some looping logic in just 3 lines of sequel.